# How to make User input choose shape of turtle

Tags: python, if-statement, user-input, python-turtle

```
import turtle


player = input('Pick Circle or Arrow')
if player == Arrow:
    turtle.Turtle()
    turtle.shape(Arrow)
elif player == Circle:
    turtle.Turtle()
    turtle.shape(Circle)
else:
    print ('Choose Circle or Arrow')
```

sorry if this is a stupid question, I am new to coding. This is for a maze game where the user can pick the shape of the turtle, I've tried a lot of stuff but it doesn't work, if you can help it would be great thanks.

Comment: [How to debug this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/): `print(repr(player), type(player), type(Arrow), player == Arrow)` above the `if` and type in `Arrow` into the prompt. You should see something like `'Arrow' <class 'str'> <class 'type'> False` which should make the problem clear.

Comment: @ggorlen `Array` and `Circle` are not defined in the code provided, so trying to do `type(Arrow)` gives a `NameError`

Comment: @Samathingamajig I initially assumed they were defined in OP's code but not shown, but after reading it again, that's probably not the case and their code is likely complete. In that case, they can see the `NameError`, then debug based on that, or on `print(repr(player), type(player))` alone. Ideally, OP would clarify ["it doesn't work"](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/) by stating the actual error they got, so there's no confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `input()` is a string, so you need to compare against it with a string. Also, "arrow" and "circle" need to be in their lowercase forms for turtle because they don't do that conversion automatically. You also need to store a reference to the created turtle, and it's easier to just do that once instead of it being in each path.

```py
import turtle

player = input('Pick Turtle or Arrow')
screen = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()
if player == "Arrow":
    t.shape("arrow")
elif player == "Circle":
    t.shape("circle")
else:
    print ('Choose Turtle or Arrow')
    screen.bye()
```

if you don't have the quotation marks around Arrow and Circle, python thinks that they are variable names.

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't test this before posting it, or else your turtle library works differently from the one on my system.

Comment: @cdlane I didn't test it, I looked up the documentation and it uses the same strings but lowercase so I assumed that it's case-insensitive, but it appears that it's not

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems with your code and @Samathingamajig's recommended changes: you don't keep a handle on the turtle you create, so it's useless to you; you use uppercase for the turtle shapes even though only lowercase is recognized; you really don't leave yourself any logic to go back and let the user correct their choice after detecting it's no good.

Here's how I might approach this problem:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

SHAPES = {
    'Circle': 'circle',
    'Arrow': 'arrow',
    'Yertle': 'turtle',
}

shape = ""

while shape not in SHAPES:

    shape = input("Pick " + ' or '.join(SHAPES) + ": ")

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()

turtle.shape(SHAPES[shape])
turtle.color('red')
turtle.forward(100)

# ...

screen.exitonclick()
```